# Where is the mic located in apple earphones?

Tags: microphone, ear-phones

I heard someone say:

> The mic in the apple earphones is located in the earbuds itself - it listens to the vibrations from your head.

I had always thought the earphones where in the volume adjuster box.

[image]

My question is: **Where is the mic located in apple earphones?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's located in remote box. You can see the inside and actual mic on [iFixIt](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Apple+EarPods+Teardown/10501) website.

[image]

Microphone is marked red **2F17 045**.

Answer (score 2):

It is below the increase, and decrease volume button